# How to generate custom builds of html/css templates by taking inputs from user

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, customization

I want to start a html/css/wordpress templates distribution website. I have coded few themes. Web themes these days are coming with too many customization features and options. But, I dont want to put everything in to a theme. I want my themes to be lean and clean. At the same time I want to give my visitors some fine control over the features that go in to the final theme.

For Example, [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) or [html5boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/).

I am ok with javascript and node.js. Are there any solutions written in JS already, so that I can read their code.

Whats the best way to do it??